How to make SwiftUI Animation repeat smoothly
I'm trying to get this neon effect to smoothly rotate around the frame in a continuous loop without using autoreverse. But i'm having trouble figuring how, as you can see at a certain point it just jumps back into the starting position when the duration is over.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NeonBorderView()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct NeonBorderView: View {
    @State private var startGradient = UnitPoint.topLeading
    @State private var endGradient = UnitPoint.bottomLeading

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .strokeBorder(
                    LinearGradient(
                        gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red,.black,.red]),
                        startPoint: startGradient,
                        endPoint: endGradient
                    ),
                    lineWidth: 5
                        
                )
                .shadow(color: .red, radius: 4)
                .onAppear {
                    let animation = Animation.linear(duration: 6 ).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
                    
                    withAnimation(animation) {
                        startGradient = UnitPoint.bottomTrailing
                        endGradient = UnitPoint.topLeading
                    }
                }

            // Content inside the border
            Text("Neon Border")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.title)
        }
        .background(Color.black)
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}



Did you intend that endGradient is initialized with bottomLeading instead of bottomTrailing? This is adding a rotation effect during the animation. To see exactly how the gradient is changing, try filling the rectangle with the gradient, instead of stroking its border. See also Snake like gradient border animation in iOS and View border gradient animation for some working solutions.
